# Meaning of "as" in context

Tags: meaning

I was reading an article in Wikipedia and came across this sentence. What meaning is 'as' carrying here?

> Pierre-Joseph Proudhon (1809–1865), influential anarchist theorist wrote: "All my economic ideas as developed over twenty-five years can be summed up in the words: agricultural-industrial federation. All my political ideas boil down to a similar formula: political federation or decentralisation.

Comment: It has a meaning similar to the relative construction _All my economic ideas, which have been developed over twenty-five years, can be summed up in the words_... .

Answer (score 1):

"All my economic ideas as developed over twenty-five years can be summed up..." could have been written as, "All my economic ideas, after developing them over twenty-five years, can be summed up..."

Answer (score 0):

**'As'** can mean '**[when considered in a specified form or relation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)**' (see #3 under 'adverb'). 'Specified' can be another way of saying *just like* or *unchanged*.  It indicates that the author (Proudhon) *hadn't altered* his views at the time of writing that quote from the views he had held over the last 25 years.  He's saying that the quote provided really is a summary of all his previous work, not a redaction, revision or refinement.

This is a *very* subtle nuance of the word 'as' compared to the alternatives provided in BillJ's comment and Steve's answer.  It *might not even be significant* - the author probably didn't deliberate over every possible word choice when writing! The variants from the previous answer and comment could easily have been substituted for the original sentence without changing the meaning. But, this is a connotation which the word 'as' in your context might specifically convey: a 'doubling down' by the author on a philosophical position.